# npm install failing due to icu4c dependency

Tags: node.js, npm-install

My npm install is failing with

```
     dyld[18001]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib
      Referenced from: <5B5BD059-AB6C-3B95-A106-6E1FD974D76D> /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.24.1_1/bin/node
      Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

zsh: abort      npm install
```

I upgraded my icu4c package to 72.1 as mentioned in some posts.

However not able to get the specific version 69 which probably node needs.

I am on node 19.6.0.

Do i need to get the 69 version of icu4c ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was on older version of node version installed through brew.

If we run brew uninstall then the old node versions are not removed if they had been explicitly installed using the version.

Uninstalled the node version explicitly and then it works.